# Configure Spring Vault with TLS

Tags: spring, ssl, amazon-ec2, hashicorp-vault

I can't find any documentation on how to properly setup Spring Vault in production environment. It's been said not to use `tls_disable = 1` in production.

I'm running vault on an empty ec2 instance, i authenticate my application manually with a token and would like to continue doing so. I'm just looking for the proper way of creating the necessary certificates so it could work with https and not http as the documentation suggests.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. For testing purposes, you can set the protocol scheme to `HTTP`:

```java
VaultEndpoint endpoint = new VaultEndpoint();
endpoint.setHost("localhost");
endpoint.setPort(8200);
endpoint.setScheme("http");

new VaultTemplate(endpoint, …)
```

2. For production: There are a few options for certificates, ranging from running a company-wide CA over setting up an intermediate CA to self-signed certificates. For Spring Vault, we created a script that helps us during testing by creating a CA and importing these certificates into a temporary truststore. You can find it [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-vault/blob/dae97c5d15457358d51a81308f700e032bcc3829/src/test/bash/create_certificates.sh) to get some inspiration. This script does not replace proper security policies and a responsible certificate handling.

Comment: Thank you for the information. So basically what you are saying is that the script is not viable for production env? I'm kind of a Jon Snow when it comes to certificates so not sure how this should be handled..

Comment: I don't know Jon Snow. Checkout StackOverflow and Amazon for Certificate Authority, SSL (TLS) and certificate resources.